# exponential equation ^ and exp give different answers

Tags: r, equation, exponential

I have an equation that I found online that I want to use on my data Y = 0.9x0.6

The 0.6 is superscript after the x

I tried two methods that yielded very different results

```
y = (0.9 * (x ^ 0.6))
```

and

```
y = (0.9 * exp(x * 0.6))
```

1. Does ^ and exp do the same thing?
2. Am I translating the equation correctly into R?

Comment: The first, `y = (0.9 * (x ^ 0.6))`, is correct. The second is using e to the power of (x * 0.6), ie would be `y = 0.9 * e^{x * 0.6}` in Latex

Comment: Thanks @alanocallaghan!

Answer (score 1):

> (x ^ 0.6)) ==  exp(x * 0.6))

is FALSE

But

```
(x ^ 0.6)) ==  expm1(x * 0.6))
```

is TRUE.

You are using the wrong function (expm1 is the correct one).

Comment: :P I reversed the logical, fixed it.